# Why is C# much slower than Java and C++ in my prime number testing

Tags: c#, java, c++

(bear with me, there's a lot of explanation before my question)

As a few of you may be aware over the last few days I have posted a fair few questions relating to performance of C++. Being a Java programmer I wanted to know was C++ worth the extra effort to specialise in, or is Java good enough for performance programming.

Anyway, I decided to write a basic (non-efficient algorithm) prime numbers program- no object creation, and to see how the 3 language compared time-wise. I wont post the code up, only for the reason that the code was exactly the same in the algorithm (except I used int instead of boolean in C++). Only the code for timing differed (and this was obviously outside the algorithm).

In summary, to calculate the first 10000 prime numbers and looped this 40 times (to exaggerate differences in speed) it took:

Java: 190.5 seconds

C++: 189 seconds

**C#: 242 seconds**

To calculate the first 100000 primes (one run) it took:

Java: 591 seconds

C++: 588 seconds

**C#: 771 seconds**

**So my question, why is C# much slower than the other 2?** I thought Java and C# would be very close timings. Here is the C# algorithm (I am aware there are quicker ways of finding prime numbers):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int NumberOfPrimesToFind = 100000;
    int NumberOfRuns = 1;

    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfRuns; k++)
    {
        FindPrimes(NumberOfPrimesToFind);

    }
    DateTime finish = DateTime.Now;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(finish-start);
    Console.In.Read();
}


static void FindPrimes(int NumberOfPrimesToFind)
{
    int NumberOfPrimes = 0;
    int CurrentPossible = 2;
    Boolean IsPrime ;

    while (NumberOfPrimes < NumberOfPrimesToFind)
    {
        IsPrime = true;

        for (int j = 2; j < CurrentPossible; j++)
        {
            if (CurrentPossible % j == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (IsPrime)
        {
            NumberOfPrimes++;
        }

        CurrentPossible++;
    }
}
```

C++

```
int main()
{
    int NumberOfPrimesToFind = 100000;
    int NumberOfRuns = 1;
    int temp;
    double dif;

    time_t start,end;
    time (&start);

    for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfRuns; k++)
    {
        FindPrimes(NumberOfPrimesToFind);

    }

    time (&end);

    //Number of seconds
    dif = difftime (end,start);

    cout << (dif);
    cin >> temp;
}

void FindPrimes(int NumberOfPrimesToFind)
{
    int NumberOfPrimes = 0;
    int CurrentPossible = 2;
    int IsPrime ;

    while (NumberOfPrimes < NumberOfPrimesToFind)
    {
        IsPrime = 1;

        for (int j = 2; j < CurrentPossible; j++)
        {
            if (CurrentPossible % j == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (IsPrime==1)
        {
            NumberOfPrimes++;
        }

        CurrentPossible++;
    }
}
```

Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int NumberOfPrimesToFind = 100000;
    int NumberOfRuns = 1;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfRuns; k++)
    {
        FindPrimes(NumberOfPrimesToFind);

    }
    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((finish-start));

}

static void FindPrimes(int NumberOfPrimesToFind)
{
    int NumberOfPrimes = 0;
    int CurrentPossible = 2;
    Boolean IsPrime ;

    while (NumberOfPrimes < NumberOfPrimesToFind)
    {
        IsPrime = true;

        for (int j = 2; j < CurrentPossible; j++)
        {
            if (CurrentPossible % j == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (IsPrime)
        {
            NumberOfPrimes++;
        }

        CurrentPossible++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the source codes are as similar as possible?

Comment: Running through the debugger or as a compiled release?

Comment: If you're going to negatively vote at least give an explanation...

Comment: @myrkos, the algorithm was EXACTLY the same, except for c++ I used int, instead of boolean and then the only difference was how to time the code.

Comment: C# and Java should be similar in _theory_, but in practice, Sun's Java compiler tends to be MUCH faster than Microsoft's C#.  It has little to do with the languages themselves.

Comment: a) you should post the C++ and Java as well, b) what mode are you running this in in C# (IDE, Debug, Release)?

Comment: Did you use VS2010 / .NET 4 ? Did you compile with Debug or Release setting ?

Comment: Please give us the java and c++ code too. The downvotes are possibly because people are concerned you want to make one of the beloved language shootout questions.

Comment: For some reason to me `findprimes` looks very wrong??? Currentpossible = 2  then you test for 2 < 2 ???

Comment: "no object creation" - you are creating objects. Boolean is an object in C#, you want to use bool instead. Not sure if that will cut down on your time or not.

Comment: @jetti no its just an alias `bool` is an alias for `System.Boolean` just as `string` and `String` are the same.

Comment: @JonH That works because the OP sets IsPrime to true initially and only will set it to false if the CurrentPossible mod 2 is 0. So it will skip the for loop when CurrentPossible is equal to 2, which means IsPrime will be true. It isn't pretty but it works.

Comment: What compilers are you using? The same code in the same language can have huge execution time differences with one or another compiler...

Comment: @Jetti I never scrolled down the code to see the rest of it.  And it sure doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Until you give better context (how you benchmarked, environment, C++ and Java code) this is a complete strawman and can only by answered with guesses, which will probably provoke religious wars.

Comment: I think I did all this in debug mode, i was just writing code, pressing f5, building and then running...

Comment: Hardly a good way to test if a candidate is prime or not :(.

Comment: @JonH, I could easilly have made this a very smart algorithm (in the inner loop you only need to loop upto root(posibleprime)-1, but the purpose was to compare ANY algorithm consistently over the 3 languages....

Comment: I am using the standard compilers which come with Visual Studio and Eclipse

Comment: `root(posibleprime)-1` -- what about 9?

Comment: Testing in Debug mode is not a good comparison. Each compiler may insert varying degrees of auxiliary code to help you debug problems. Compile and run them with all optimizations enabled, no debugger attached, and post those results.

Comment: First of all using these kind of examples to try and measure the performance difference between Java & C++ isn't very indicative. The power of C++ vs Java comes in more forms than just simple arithmetic. What version of VS are you using? VS Express for example isn't an optimizing compiler for at least C++.

Comment: "I think I did all this in debug mode." Then your timings are completely unreliable. Run it in release mode, without attaching the debugger (i.e. Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio).

Comment: I'd go with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Personally I'm slightly surprised java is basically as fast as c++ in this example

Comment: @Austin, can we please concentrate on the fact this algorithm was consistent across the 3 languages and not how great the algorithm is. Making the algorithm better wouldn't achieve anything....

Comment: @Ylisar: Actually, VCExpress does come with an optimizing compiler. You're thinking of the older 2003-era free compiler stuff. It doesn't let you do 64-bit compiles, but it does let you optimize.

Comment: Codes like this are shit for comparisons between languages because they essentially boil down to the same. You see this in Java vs. C++. Not very interesting, is it? To see differences you need to implement more complex, extensible architectures (such as the parametric `sort` routine). *This* is where C++ shines, for instance.

Comment: Debugger hooks tend to slow things down. The compiler to CIL generates more code with nops for hooks to be placed, on and the Jitter avoids lots of optimization to allow for easier debugging. Compile in release and launch without attaching the debugger. (Ctrl-F5).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - I had to +1 that because I have a german peer working on an implementation with me and you sound just like him.  He always starts with `Codes like this are shit...`

Comment: Its VS2010 professional. I just ran the code using ctrl+f5 (release mode?) and it's the same timing for C#.

Comment: Look at http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ , e.g. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Cool, glad to see they've changed :)

Comment: *Ctrl+F5* does not magically put you in Release mode; you need to change the build configuration (dropdown menu) to Release. That key combination starts the program without the debugger attached.

Comment: @Praetorian, just found what you mentioned and now re-running.

Comment: Ok, release mode- same as Java and C#!!! Sorry guy's, as you've probably guessed i'm not an experienced programmer so didn't know about the release/debug execution modes. Well I learnt something from asking this question so I'm glad I did ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About C#:

First of all, instead of datetime you should use stopwatch.
Datetime is not reliable for code timing.

Second, are you sure you are executing it in release mode with visual studio closed?
If visual studio is open or you are launching with F5 the JIT will not optimize the code!

So... use stopwatch and close all instances of visual studio.
You have to change project options, you should have a combobox, in the top toolbar, where you can read "Debug", just click on it and select "Release" or go to right click on your project, properties, and change it to release mode. Then to avoid every kind of problems, close all instances of visual studio and launch with double click on the executable.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

CTRL+F5 don't compile in release mode, it just launch the executable in selected compilation mode without attacching the process for debugging, so if it was compiled in debug, it will launch the executable compiled in debug mode without debugging it.

Then i would suggest to you to avoid the use of the boolean variable, each branch condition can slow down the CPU, you can do it using an integer. This is valid for all languages, not only C#.

```
static void Main()
{
    const int NumberOfPrimesToFind = 100000;
    const int NumberOfRuns = 1;

    System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfRuns; k++)
    {
        FindPrimes(NumberOfPrimesToFind);
    }
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void FindPrimes(int NumberOfPrimesToFind)
{
    int NumberOfPrimes = 0;
    int CurrentPossible = 2;

    while (NumberOfPrimes < NumberOfPrimesToFind)
    {
        int IsPrime = 1;

        for (int j = 2; j < CurrentPossible; j++)
        {
            if (CurrentPossible % j == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        NumberOfPrimes += IsPrime;
        CurrentPossible++;
    }
}
```

When you compile it with C++ in release mode however since input parameters are constants C++ compiler is smart enough to perform some of the computation at compile time (the power of modern C++ compilers!). This magic is usually used with templates too, STL (standard template library) for example is very, very slow in debug mode but very fast in release mode.

In this case the compiler is totally ruling out your function because the output of your function is not used. Try to make it return an integer, the number of found primes, and print it.

```
int FindPrimes(int NumberOfPrimesToFind)
{
    int NumberOfPrimes = 0;
    int CurrentPossible = 2;
    while (NumberOfPrimes < NumberOfPrimesToFind)
    {
        int IsPrime = 1;

        for (int j = 2; j < CurrentPossible; j++)
        {
            if (CurrentPossible % j == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        NumberOfPrimes += IsPrime;
        CurrentPossible++;
    }
    return NumberOfPrimes ;
}
```

If you are curious about this aspect of the C++ compiler, take a look at the template metaprogramming for example, there exists a formal proof that C++ compiler is turing complete. As wikipedia quotes "In addition, templates are a compile time mechanism in C++ that is Turing-complete, meaning that any computation expressible by a computer program can be computed, in some form, by a template metaprogram prior to runtime." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B

However I really hope you are using this algorithm only to try to understand how the three different compilers\systems behave, because, of course, this is the worst algorithm you can use to find prime numbers, as pointed out in other answers :)

Comment: To run in release mode, is that the ctrl+f5 someone else mentioned?

Comment: @user997112 you should be able to do that yes.

Comment: Thanks JonH, I believe I just tried that- but i'm just trying again with the bool changed to int and will let you know the result.

Comment: No...That just turns the debugger off.  Go into the Release folder and run the application.  Do not use VS to start the application

Comment: ctrl+f5 by itself will not run in release mode.  You need to change the build configuration.

Comment: CTRL+F5 don't compile in release mode, it just launch it in selected mode without attacching the process for debugging. you have to change project options to force C# to compile in release mode, and as I said, close every instance of visual studio and execute with double click on the executable.

Comment: @user997112: You need to change the Drop Down on the configuration from Debug to Release, otherwise it compiles with a lot of extra debugging information.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx

Comment: Hi guys, yes I figured it out after I saw one of the comments in the other message :)

The time in release mode was the same- 47 seconds, actually quicker than C++ and Java! Thank for your help

Comment: Well you should do the same in C++ and Java, probably the timing of C# will be the same as C++, don't think faster.

Comment: @ Salvatore Previti, a little unsure if this can be correct, but when I change the c++ from debug to release it goes from 47 seconds to 0 ?!?!?!

Comment: It can be possible because you are performing a constant time computation, your input parameters are constants. C++ compiler will avoid the loops and performe some of the computations at compile time. I didn't think about this :) You should try to input your variables for example with scanf or with a virtual method returning an integer value :) C++ is quite powerful.

Comment: @Salvatore it could be the termination bug, that compiler drops a piece of code without proving that it terminates. see http://blog.regehr.org/archives/140 *C Compilers Disprove Fermat’s Last Theorem*

Comment: Wow irreputable! This article is AMAZING. Thanks for sharing, very informative and very mind bending :) Bookmarked. Now i'm going to compile some code to see the implication of this :) lol.

Comment: However no, this is not the case. C compiler is throwing out totally the execution of the method because the output of the method is not used, there is no output to use, so he is right and this is not the problem reported in the blog page, no theorem was disproved here :) the compiler is right. If we add a printf("%d\n", numberoffoundprimes) for example the compiler is forced to use that code. There is nothing to compute so the compiler delete the function.

Comment: In this case, the code terminates, and the compiler is right to eliminate it; however it's unclear if the compiler has proved that the code terminates. If it's not proved, I'd side with the author and argue that this is a compiler bug (which happens to render correct behavior in this case). In Java, if compiler/VM cannot prove that a code terminates, it will never optimize it off.

Comment: Yes the correct behaviour is indeed to not eliminate the non-provable code, however, there are some rare problem (see Goedel) that cannot neither be proved or disproved! I mean, what if the compiler cannot prove or disprove that the given code can or cannot be proved? I'm curious to see what java or c++ would do in this case :) Omg we are opening the gates of hell with these questions.

Comment: However i tried the code putting the integer return value and printing it, the code seems to execute, but in my machine with 100000 prime numbers is too slow, so i reduced it to 10000 :)

Answer (score 1):

The C++ and C# algorithms appear to be extremely similar if not identical. Since there isn't any obvious code difference that would account for the performance, I'd suspect that there may be locality or optimizer differences. The only way to know for sure is to profile two of the different versions and see where they perform differently.

Comment: The one key diff suggested was to use `int` rather then the `bool` in C#.  Not sure if that makes too much of a difference.

Comment: @JonH, have changed that and currently re-running the code in release mode.

Answer (score -1):

When comparing languages you should try to optimise the code first.  Otherwise you could be comparing how well it executes inefficient code, which might not be very meaningful.  For example, in all the benchmarks I have seen where Java outperforms C++ significantly, they are ones which don't do anything useful. ;)

For the longer test which looks for 100,000 primes in 40 runs.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int numberOfPrimesToFind = 100000;
    int numberOfRuns = 40;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRuns; k++)
        findPrimes(numberOfPrimesToFind);

    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %.2f seconds to loop %,d times%n", finish/1e3, numberOfRuns);
}

static void findPrimes(int numberOfPrimesToFind) {
    int numberOfPrimes = 0;
    int currentPossible = 2;

    while (numberOfPrimes < numberOfPrimesToFind) {
        boolean isPrime = isPrime(currentPossible);

        if (isPrime) {
            numberOfPrimes++;
        }

        currentPossible++;
    }
}

private static boolean isPrime(int currentPossible) {
    if ((currentPossible & 1) == 0) return false;
    for (int j = 3; j * j <= currentPossible; j += 2)
        if (currentPossible % j == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

prints

```
Took 9.26 seconds to loop 40 times
```

The moral of the story is that the algorithm you use is often more important than the language you use.

Comment: This answer seems to be irrelevant to the question asked. Why, with the original algorithm, is the C# implementation slower than the other two?